# Page to cut off at window with html & body display: hidden

Tags: html, css

**Note: based on the answers by [@aavrug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3129610/aavrug) and [@kukkuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6231153/kukkuz), I have restructured my question so that it fully conveys what I am trying to ask.*

I have a page layout which has a top nav-bar and a side nav-bar. It also has a main part in which the data is shown. As I only want the main part to scroll, I set `html, body { overflow: hidden; }` and `.main { overflow-y: auto; }`. I have further transformed the page into a flex-box after [kukkuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6231153/kukkuz)'s answer. This is what I have so far:

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex-flow: column;
}
div {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  margin: 2px;
}
.top,
.side {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}
.side span {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.top span{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.top {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  /* This might be code-smell as a div already is a block element, but removing it doesn't make the layout work */
}
.side {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 128px;
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.big {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #369;
}
.small {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #a12;
}
```

```html
<div class="container column">
  <div class="top"><span>Where is the green border at the side??? ></span></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side"><span>Where is the green border at the bottom??? \/<span></div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

It seems to work as planned (what I was running into earlier is that the `.main` - `.window` in the old question - was expanding below the page and thus you could not scroll the entire page length); however, if you look at the bottom and right side of the resulting page, you will see that the borders which are supposed to be there, are not there, giving to the idea that the page does not actually cut off at the bottom of the window (on the right side, the ">" I put even disappears into the side of the window a bit).

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2wtxq7m/1/) as well.

> Thus, my question is, how would one properly use `html, body { overflow: hidden; }` while still containing the laid out elements so that they are *fully* visible.

In my example above I use `html, body { height: 100%; }` I have also tried `height: 100vh;` but that did not work.

*P.S. If it seems that I am asking a separate question to the un-revised question, I am not. This is still the same problem, just now I have fully provided all elements to it. Tku.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a `flexbox`:

1. First put `height: 100%` on the `body` and remove the default margins.
2. Wrap your `window` into a `flexbox` like this:

   ```
   <div class="window-wrapper">
      <div class="window">
        <!-- more code here -->
      </div>
   </div>

   .window-wrapper{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100%;
   }
   ```

And there you go. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.window-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.window {
  margin-top: 128px;
  margin-left: 128px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.big {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #369;
}
.small {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #a12;
}
```

```html
<div class="window-wrapper">
  <div class="window">
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      I'm big
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      I'm small
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated answer**:

1. Remove the floats
2. Wrap the `window` with a div with styles like this:

   ```
   .window-wrapper {
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     flex: 1;
   }
   .window {
     height: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. The container that wraps the sidebar and the content should have `flex: 1` and should not have `height: 100%`. So added this style:

   ```
   .container-inner {
     display: flex;
     margin: 0;
     flex: 1;
   }
   ```
4. Removed `height: 100%` from the `side` too.
5. To finish things up, added `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements to prevent the overflows.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container-inner {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.column {
  flex-flow: column;
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 2px;
}

.top {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  /* This might be code-smell as a div already is a block element, but removing it doesn't make the layout work */
}

.side {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 128px;
}

.window-wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.window {
  height: 100%;
}

.big {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #369;
}

.small {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #a12;
}
```

```html
<div class="container column">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="window-wrapper">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
      <div class="big">
        I'm big
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        I'm small
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tku, good idea. I editted my OP to be more precise. Maybe you can give some insight into how to handle the revised question?

Comment: @4lackof check the updated answer if that answers your questions... Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A small modificaton required in your div

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.window {
  margin: 64px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.big {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #369;
}

.small {
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #a12;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    I'm big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    I'm small
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: makes sense, now what if I need to get the `.window` to fill the remaining space (think of the `margin-left` and `margin-top` as other divs - I edited the code on the OP to reflect this - surrounding the `.window`). I tried replacing `height` with `min-height: 1%;` but that did not work. Any suggestions to make it work that way?

Comment: First of all I am not following you, can you please show me what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you remove the margin from ```.window``` class you will get a div which will cover the entire body by width and seems you are setting height dynamically.

Comment: Tku, good idea. I editted my OP to be more precise. Maybe you can give some insight into how to handle the revised question?

Comment: With your new modifications see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/q4ev3k3h/)