# Can Flex be used vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css, flexbox

Ok so i've run into a bit of a problem with flex css.

Basically i have created a web app and to separate each tab i have used icons (a little js to show and hide the divs) and flex to align the icons.

So I have a situation like this:

http://numerco.com/wp-content/uploads/NUA/flex.jpg

Apologies for lack of source code, but my problem lies with the content div.

I would like to use column flex to fill the remainder of the screen available how ever it only seems that you can only have 1 flex container and flex in one direction, is this correct?

Also is there any other way to divide the remaining space available for content?

Comment: guess you can use nested flexboxes for this... see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482088/css-page-to-cut-off-at-window-with-html-body-display-hidden/39482627#39482627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested flexboxes, this does the job:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.row div {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>1
    </div>
    <div>2
    </div>
    <div>3
    </div>
    <div>4
    </div>
    <div>5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt,</p>
    <p>sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this worked like a treat i think my problem was from trying to apply flex through classes on my div. using .row nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
} was a game changer thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest them like this

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.icon-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <i class="icon-1">A</i>
    <i class="icon-2">A</i>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, in case anyone has the same problem as me this is the code for exactly what i wanted to achieve (with content expanding to fill remaining space)

```
<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.row div {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.itemconfiguration {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <nav>

        <ul>

          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>

        </ul>

      </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="itemconfiguration">

    <p>Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque     adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt,</p>
  <p>Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque     adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt,</p>
 <p>Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque     adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt,</p>
<p>Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque     adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt,</p>

   </div>

 </div>
```